# How can I view a list of pages to link to in the Navigation module?

Tags: navigation

I am learning Drupal, and currently creating my first navigation menu. When I click 'Add Link' I can see this view:

[image]

This allows me to type a value into the path field to link to, however what I am looking for is a list of current Pages or Content nodes within the site to link to. Surely you cannot be expected to remember the list of current paths that exist within the entire site everytime you want to add something to your navigation menu.

As an example of what I mean, if you create a link in the Wordpress backend, you are shown a dialog which shows a list of current site content to link to as below:

[image]

**How can I view a list of pages/content to link to in the Navigation module?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal has designed this a bit differently. Instead of creating content and then creating the menu, you can add a menu link when you create or edit content.

[image: Screen shot]